# Magento2: Calling a protected class, compile error: Incorrect dependency

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm getting the following error for a custom module on compile in Magento 2.1.3

```
Incorrect dependency in class NAMESPACE\MODULE\Block\SOMEBLOCK in /home/www/app/code/namespace/module/Block/Someblock.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
```

Briefly, the block code looks like this;

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Someblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_fileSystem = $filesystem;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

}
```

The issue is that the code is injecting \Magento\Framework\Filesystem in the construct when it already exists in the inherited parent class.

For non private classes I know we can call those within the block class with;

```
$this->someclass
```

But how do we call private ones?  I've tried this;

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Someblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    //\Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    array $data = []
)
{
    //$this->_fileSystem = $filesystem;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function dosomething() {

   $fileSystem = $this->_fileSystem;
}

}
```

But I get $_filesystem is undefined.

Here is the constructor from the parent class \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

```
public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
{
    $this->validator = $context->getValidator();
    $this->resolver = $context->getResolver();
    $this->_filesystem = $context->getFilesystem();
    $this->templateEnginePool = $context->getEnginePool();
    $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
    $this->_appState = $context->getAppState();
    $this->templateContext = $this;
    $this->pageConfig = $context->getPageConfig();
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Any feedback gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this one,

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Someblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    public $myfileobj;
    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function dosomething() 
    {
        $this->myfileobj = $this->getFilesystem();
    }

}
```

You can used $this->myfileobj in another place as well.

Comment: This is what I tried also - it produces error;

Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: filesystem

Comment: $fileSystem only used dosomething() this function, If you need to used that in another function, then you need to used another variable.

Comment: sorry typo, this;

Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined property: Namespace\Module\Block\Someblock::$fileSystem

I'm calling it within a function directly with $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR)->getAbsolutePath() . 'instagram_timer';

Comment: thanks, it was a case mismatch between the parent constructor and my module (doh)

Comment: If above answer will help you, please accept it will help another in community.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the answer was right in front of me!  The parent constructor was;

```
public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
{
$this->validator = $context->getValidator();
$this->resolver = $context->getResolver();
$this->_filesystem = $context->getFilesystem();
$this->templateEnginePool = $context->getEnginePool();
$this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
$this->_appState = $context->getAppState();
$this->templateContext = $this;
$this->pageConfig = $context->getPageConfig();
parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

The variable is;

```
$this->_filesystem
```

NOT

```
$this->_fileSystem
```

Which I had.